# A WPF App fails when coming out of hibernate mode

Tags: wpf, windows, .net-3.5, hibernate-mode

I have a WPF application that fails to come out of the timed sleep, followed by hibernate.
The render thread seems to be failing during initialization. I tried removing hardware acceleration to check that it's not graphics card related, but that did not help.

Here is an exception along with the stacktrace:

ERROR An unspecified error occurred on the render thread.
   Stack trace:    at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyPartitionIsZombie(Int32 failureCode)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyChannelMessage()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()

I googled around, and people suggest that it might have something to do with AllowsTransparency property being set to true; however, i did not see this issue when running a simple test app.

Any ideas about the exception and possible causes/solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

967634  FIX: You may experience several issues when you render graphics by using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) in an application
[967634](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;967634)

Note: Unfortunately, you'll probably have to call. However, it's free even if they charge you at first, they *will* refund your money if all you do is ask them for the fix.

Comment: thanks a lot, that just did the trick,
I was also able to find the download without calling:
http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?s=a11a52806667765ef890c84e8f5dff3a&autocom=downloads&req=download&code=confirm_download&id=10673